# How to find state prices?

Tags: option-pricing, finance, no-arbitrage-theory, matrix

I am trying to find out how to solve state prices, but I do not know what I am supposed to do, my professor has given a solution to this problem as being (0.060 0.417 0.476), but I can't figure out how he gets there and he says the deadline for asking questions are over.

[image: Problem information]

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seek the price of a hedging portfolio which replicates the payoff of an Arrow-Debreu asset.

### State 1

We seek $w_1,w_2,w_3$ such that

\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
1.05 & 1.8 & 1\\
1.05 & 1 & 1\\
1.05 &1 &1.1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
w_1\\
w_2\\
w_3
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

[With a little help](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=systems+of+equations+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%2C+%22equation1%22%7D+-%3E%221.05x+%2B+1.8y+%2B+1z%3D1%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22+-%3E+%7B%7B%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%2C+%22equation2%22%7D+-%3E%221.05x+%2B+y%2Bz%3D0%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%2C+%22equation3%22%7D+-%3E%221.05x%2By%2B1.1z%3D0%22), the solution is $w_1=-\frac{25}{21}$, $w_2=\frac{5}{4}$  and $w_3=0$.

Thus, because the price of each asset is one ($p_i=1$), the state price for state 1 is
\begin{align}
q_1 = p_1w_1 + p_2w_2+p_3w_3 = \frac{5}{84}\approx0.060.
\end{align}

### The other states

To find the price of state 2, you have to solve
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
1.05 & 1.8 & 1\\
1.05 & 1 & 1\\
1.05 &1 &1.1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
w_1\\
w_2\\
w_3
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
and set $q_2=w_1+w_2+w_3$.

For state price 3, you have to look at
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
1.05 & 1.8 & 1\\
1.05 & 1 & 1\\
1.05 &1 &1.1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
w_1\\
w_2\\
w_3
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
and again set $q_3=w_1+w_2+w_3$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the super solution @Kevin, I finally get it now.